# Can not download anything from https://mitmproxy.org/downloads/#4.0.4/

Tags: ssl, download, ssl-certificate, mitmproxy

Can't download anything from [here](https://mitmproxy.org/downloads/#4.0.4/)

I've tried to download the file several times from different Linux machines:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --secure-protocol=TLSv1 https://snapshots.mitmproxy.org/4.0.4/mitmproxy-4.0.4-windows-installer.exe
--2019-12-19 16:26:46--  https://snapshots.mitmproxy.org/4.0.4/mitmproxy-4.0.4-windows-installer.exe
Resolving snapshots.mitmproxy.org... 143.204.101.60, 143.204.101.113, 143.204.101.39, ...
Connecting to snapshots.mitmproxy.org|143.204.101.60|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Unable to establish SSL connection.

wget --no-check-certificate --secure-protocol=TLSv1 https://snapshots.mitmproxy.org/4.0.4/mitmproxy-4.0.4-windows-installer.exe.
--2019-12-19 15:27:51--  https://snapshots.mitmproxy.org/4.0.4/mitmproxy-4.0.4-windows-installer.exe.
Resolving snapshots.mitmproxy.org (snapshots.mitmproxy.org)... 13.32.43.97, 13.32.43.82, 13.32.43.47, ...
Connecting to snapshots.mitmproxy.org (snapshots.mitmproxy.org)|13.32.43.97|:443... connected.
GnuTLS: Error in the pull function.
Unable to establish SSL connection.


curl -L0 https://snapshots.mitmproxy.org/4.0.4/mitmproxy-4.0.4-windows-installer.exe
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to snapshots.mitmproxy.org:443
```

And finally, FireFox says `PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR`.

Any way to help me to download the mentioned file ?

Comment: Works without problems here. Are you sure your network connection is direct (no intercepting proxy or network interception system in-between)? Also SSLLabs doe not identify any SSL/TLS problems on these servers: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=snapshots.mitmproxy.org&latest

Comment: This looks very much like some DPI based security system (firewall or similar) in your network is blocking the access, i.e. initial TCP connection works but as soon as the domain is known the connection will be blocked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies.
My 1st host was in Russia, 2nd was in Netherlands (Digital Ocean)...

Both hosts seems to be under heavy DPI.

I've managed to download the file through TOR.